# Getting an array as a field from result row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm pretty new to databases, so my question is:

Let's say that we have two tables: **Users** and **Orders**

Is it possible (and how do I do it) to list all users with their data (First & Last name, birthdate etc) and associated orders in one query? So the result should look something like this:

```
|------------------------------|
| John Doe  |  Order 1 details |
|           |  Order 2 details |
|           |  Order 3 details |
|------------------------------|
| Janny Hoe |  Order x details |
|           |  Order y details |
|------------------------------|
```

So you got the point? Each row from table1 has a field which contains multiple rows from table2? I've heard MySQL doesn't return multidimensional arrays, so how does it return something like this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Table structure could be something like this:

```
TABLE users:
id | name

TABLE orders:
id | user_id | date_ordered | other unrelevant data...
```

I know this is doable with joins, but what bugs me is what will it return?
Will result have field orders which would be array containing orders row data like $result[0]['orders'][0]['date_ordered'] or something like that ?

Comment: Please provide the table structures

Comment: Sounds like you need to take a look at joins.  See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html  But your table fields will also depend on how effective that will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a LEFT join (if there is a possibility that a user does not have any orders) and then gather the results in an array, based on the user ID:

```
SELECT Users.id, Users.name, Order.detail
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Order
ON Users.id= Order.user;
```

Ex:

```
$userOrders = array();

$sql = 'SELECT Users.id, Users.name, Order.detail
        FROM Users
        LEFT JOIN Order
        ON Users.id= Order.user';

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $userOrders[$row['user_id']][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: And if there were multiple orders, would there be an array in $row containing details for all orders associated with user?

Thanks for help anyways

Comment: Each row will be a separate order. If you try out the LEFT join and var_dump() the rows, you'll see what I mean. You'll get the right data back, its just that its up to you to group it into a multidimensional array that is keyed by the user ID.